# barTintColor in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

what will be the best way to change navigation bar color in case all i have is an hex color: `#292e3f`

its work fine with something like that:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

but i cant figure out how to insert a hex, i tried usin this site:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/web-color-to-uicolor-convertor/

but it dosent seems to work:

```
var navBarColor = UIColor (red:0.161,green:0.18,blue:0.247,alpha:1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = navBarColor
```

Comment: What do you mean that the second code block doesn't work?  Is the bar the wrong color?

Comment: I had a problem with that cuz its in CGColor and i got an error trying to use it with UIColor the second way "Glynbeard" showed workd great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own custom hex extension to accomplish this fairly easily. For instance something like this may work:

```
extension UIColor {
     convenience init(hex: Int) {
            let r = hex / 0x10000
            let g = (hex - r*0x10000) / 0x100
            let b = hex - r*0x10000 - g*0x100
            self.init(red: CGFloat(r)/255, green: CGFloat(g)/255, blue: CGFloat(b)/255, alpha: 1)
        }
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x292e3f)
```

To get the hex color you want.

Comment: No problem, glad I could assist.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to, you may find it easier to use one of the many categories kicking around that add hex support to `UIColor`. There are a lot of Objective-C implementations on Github, and a cursory search found a Swift one too:

https://github.com/yeahdongcn/UIColor-Hex-Swift